# Loop through JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I loop on all of these (objects ? I don't know) with Javascript?

```
{
  test1: {
    name: "1",
    fa: true,
  },
  test2: {
    name: "2",
    fa: false,
  },
  test3: {
    name: "3",
    fa: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Look up `Object.entries`, `Object.values`, `Object.keys`

Comment: I'm really not able to find anything, sorry ..

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Hello @ThumChoonTat, I was on this post and did my best, but how can I get the key2 value ? Here is my code : https://pastebin.com/npwknHCA Thanks !

Comment: Just like how you get the value of `[key]`, `p[key][key2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the returned array of `Object.keys(object)` or a `for...in` loop

```
const  obj = {
  "test1": {
    "name": "1",
    "2fa": true,
  },
  "test2": {
    "name": "2",
    "2fa": false,
  },
  "test3": {
    "name": "3",
    "2fa": true,
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  console.log(obj[key]);
});
for(const key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to loop through these objects;

```
var objects={
      "test1": {
        "name": "1",
        "2fa": true,
      },
      "test2": {
        "name": "2",
        "2fa": false,
      },
      "test3": {
        "name": "3",
        "2fa": true,
      }
    }

    for (var key in objects) {
        if (objects.hasOwnProperty(key)) {        
            var obj= objects[key]
            console.log(key);
            console.log("Name: " + obj["name"]);
            console.log("2fa:" + obj["2fa"]);
        }
    }
```